# ng-show binding to string expression in angular

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

Is there a way to bind a ng-show expression to a string which contains the bind expression itself?

For Instance:

```
field={};
field.a=true;
field.showExpression='a == true';

<input ng-show="field.showExpression">
```

I´ve tried `<input ng-show="{{field.showExpression}}">` as well, but none of them seems to work.

I want the bind to stay active, so that when the field.a object changes from true to false the expression gets evaluated again, hiding the input.

Just as background, i´m trying to implement dependant dropdowns, so my showExpressions should be of form field.showExpression='maindropdownValue!=null', and whenever the maindropdown which will be bound to the maindropdownValue gets selected the second one gets displayed.

I´m using angular 1.0.8

Comment: You just need `ng-show="field.a"`. When a changes, the ng-show will notice it, and will show/hide depending on the new value of `a`.

Comment: Yes, but i just can´t do it this way here, since i really want to use an expression which will come from the server in a very generic way. I think @Lame-up-duck answer is the way to go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

showExpression is evalued as a String not as a JS code. You have to use a function instead.

```
$scope.isTrue = function() {
    return $scope.field.a; // or a more complex check
}
//
ng-show="isTrue()"
```

if you only have to check for a boolean, you can check var directly in the view:

```
ng-show="field.a"
```

If you really want to use eval, this is what you want:

ng-show="$parent.$eval(field.showExpression)"

link: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: Thanks I´ll give that $parent.$eval a look! In my case, perhaps it will not be exactly like this, since i´m using it inside a directive and thus the $parent might point to some other location.

Comment: Just as soon as I asked here I got it working, by doing a function here (just as you suggested too). On the function I used plain javascript eval in order to eval the expression, but I´ll surely take a look at your proposed solution ASAP

Comment: Just for noticing, my main concern was whether that function would be called once I changed the "main" dropdown, which I just realized would work by testing it against the app. But, do you know how angular knows that he has to call that function once again? would be nice to understaand that

Comment: Angular uses a circular data-binding model. Each time something in the model changes, angular will reload "affected" components. Reading **Common Pitfalls** paragraph in angular FAQ may answer better: http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

Comment: Just tested $parent.$eval(field.showExpression), but couldn´t manage this to work. Perhaps, as I told is just a matter of using the right scope, since it´s inside many nested directives (so, perhaps $parent.$parent.$parent... $eval(field.showExpression) _

Comment: I´m just marking it as accepted, since the whole point of it consists of extracting a function. The only reservation I´d make is about the $parent.$eval which I really could not manage to work here (maybe you could somehow edit your answer pointing that for future references).  Thanks for the extra clarifications as well :)

Comment: I'm searching for something about named $scopes but with no luck. I'll edit as soon as I found a solution because I will need for sure :)